# How can I embed a facebook photo album with comments and tagging directly into a webpage?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tagging, photos

I want to be able to embed a facebook photo album complete with comments and and photo tagging directly on a webpage. Basically I want it to look as close as possible to the way it does on facebook.com.

So far the only solution I found is to just embed the pictures from the album without comments or photo tagging capabilities. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It would be neat to have this all wrapped up and ready to drop in, but I haven't found anything like that. You have to get all the info, and use your own css.

I use fql: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/
For instance (this is a lot more than I actually have ever used):

```
q0 = "SELECT aid,name,descripton FROM album WHERE owner="+theirID;
q1 = "SELECT pid,aid,src_small,caption,object_id FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM #q0)";
q2 = "SELECT fromid,text,id,username,likes FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM #q1)";
q3= "SELECT * FROM photo_tag WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM #q1)";

FB.api( { method: 'fql.multiquery', queries: {"q0": q0,"q1":q1,"q2":q2,"q3":q3}}, function(re) {
// sort out the mess
// eg albumDescription = re[0].fql_result_set[item].description;
});
```